# Procedure to input number and output varchar2

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

I need to write a procedure to input let's say a rep_id and then output the rep_name that corresponds to the rep_id.

After that, I need to use another procedure to call the above procedure.

Here is what I have for the first procedure.

```
create or replace procedure p_inout
(v_rep_id in number)
As
v_first_name varchar2(20);
v_last_name varchar2(20);
begin
select first_name,last_name into v_first_name, v_last_name
from rep
where rep_id = v_rep_id;
dbms_output.put_line(v_first_name||' '||v_last_name);
end p_inout;
/

Execute p_inout(100);
```

And here is my procedure to call the above procedure

```
create or replace procedure p_call
is
v_first_name varchar2(20);
v_last_name varchar2(20);
begin
p_inout(100);
dbms_output.put_line(v_first_name||' '||v_last_name);
end p_call;
/
execute p_call
```

I was able to get the result but one guy told me that my call procedure should be like this

```
Create or replace procedure p_call
Is
V_name varchar2(20);
Begin
P_inout(100,v_name); --100 is a rep id
Dbms_output.Put_line(v_name);
End;
/
Execute p_call
```

Doesn't my procedure to call and his call procedure produce the same result?

Comment: How does a `rep_id` correspond to a `rep_name`? Are they columns in the same table, or different tables or is there a specific correlation that you want to hard code?

Comment: What are the data types?

Comment: @MT0 the data type for rep_id is number, while the names are varchar2(20). They are columns in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE minions (
  rep_id    DATE   CONSTRAINT minions__rep_id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  rep_name  NUMBER CONSTRAINT minions__rep_name__nn NOT NULL
                   CONSTRAINT minions__rep_name__u UNIQUE
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myCatWasSick (
  p_rep_id   IN  minions.rep_id%TYPE,
  p_rep_name OUT minions.rep_name%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT rep_name
  INTO   p_rep_name
  FROM   minions
  WHERE  rep_id = p_rep_id;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    p_rep_name := NULL;
END myCatWasSick;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE releaseTheBadgers
IS
  the_badger NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
  myCatWasSick( SYSDATE + 1, the_badger );
  // Do something with the_badger.
END releaseTheBadgers;
/
```